# Vert.x, Elastic Beanstalk, and HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vert.x

I have a Vert.x server running on a single-instance Elastic Beanstalk server, and I'm trying to configure it to operate over HTTPS. I've set up the NS records and A record in AWS Route 53 to map the subdomain to my instance (pinging the subdomain succeeds), requested (and verified) the certificate from ACM, and opened up port 443 in my EC2 security group. But I can't quite figure out how to "attach" the certificate to my domain (if that's somehow necessary) or to get port 443 properly mapped to my Vert.x server.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to get port 443 properly mapped to my Vert.x server.

If you use ACM for the SSL certificate, you have to setup application load balancer. The process is detailed in:

- [How can I configure HTTPS for my Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/)

To enable load balancer for your EB environment, you have to change [EB environment type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html#using-features.managing.changetype) to `Load-balanced` if you already don't have that.

With the load balancer, you don't have to modify your application at all, as HTTPS will be fully handled by the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks! I was discouraged by all the .ebextensions configuration details there, but it turns out I didn't even need to do any of that.